# Does Firefox 4 implement any addon architectural changes

Tags: javascript, c++, c, firefox, firefox-addon

There is an open source firefox addon that I have attempted to test with firefox 4. The installation fails with an error advising that the addon is incompatiable with firefox 4.

From the best of my research I have determined that this is because the install.rdf file contains the following code.

```
<em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
<em:maxVersion>3.6.*</em:maxVersion>
```

Now I am assuming that modifiying this value should allow the install to succeed and the addon be enabled. (Working on recompiling it all now)

However what I am wondering is if there have been any significant "breaking changes" in the way the addon architecture is implemented in firefox 4 and if so could anyone please provide some insight into these changes?

Comment: last time I have checked addons in firefox are coded in javascript and xml mixture. XUL. Plus you should try to install the addon and see if it is working.

Comment: Thats what Im currently trying to do (Have no C experience)... You are correct that the addons are written in javascript but in this case it calls various C or C++ code (not sure exactly)... It is quite a complicated addon and my concern is that that there may be subtle bugs I might not notice.

Comment: Note that you can test extensions not yet marked as compatible without editing them. See Addon Compatibility Reporter https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/15003/ . You can also check the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/compatibility/reporter/ for reports from other people who tried the addon using the Reporter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start with [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Updating_extensions_for_Firefox_4) at MDC.

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich: note that there's no extensive list of changes that might affect add-ons, since it would be many thousands of items. So if you're worried about subtle bugs as you mention in another comment, the answer is testing, testing, and testing (unit tests, if they exist, manual testing, asking people to test a beta version for you and so on).